# empty variables when i use a region template for a specific node

Tags: theming, hooks

My goal is to serve the drupal header region on a specific URL so another application can get my drupal header and consume it.

my menu is well working, and is called in region--header.html.twig like that :

```
<header class="header {% if is_admin %} header-isadmin{% endif %}">
<div class="header__overlay"></div>
<div class="header__mask"></div>
{{ elements.altabigmenu }}
</header>
```

So, i created a page with a specific URL and used `HOOK_theme_suggestions_node_alter` to change its template with my region :

```
if ($node != NULL) {
    $url_alias = Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/' . $node->id());
}

if (isset($url_alias)) {
    if ($url_alias == "/ap/nav/header") {
      $suggestions[] = "region__header";
    }
}
```

in the end my node is rendered using the region template, but the `{{ elements.altabigmenu }}` tag returns nothing. My first guess was to inject the menu via the $variables array in preprocess_node, but i don't get variables declared in `HOOK_preprocess_node`

Comment: Your likely problem is that you're trying to render a region in the context of a node, so none of the regions variables are set. As an alternative you could create a custom controller in a custom module which returns the relevant render array for the header to be themed